# Unknown directive when adding a new default page in nginx

Tags: nginx, default-document

I am using nginx to host a website and following is the current configuration which is defined at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite`

**Config**

```
server {  
   listen 80;  
   root /var/www/mysite;  
   index.php index.htm index.html;  
}
```

Problem is as soon as I set another page as default nginx start throwing error

`unknown directive "somepage.php" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite`

**New Config**

```
server {  
       listen 80;  
       root /var/www/mysite;  
       somepage.php index.php index.htm index.html;  
    }
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong here. Can you please check?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html

Comment: Oh I got it. The `index` that is written at the start of line is a keyword and is required.